# Meteor: Custom AutoForm with array of objects in afEachArrayItem blocks

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm working on dictionary app, and schema have a nested structure.

```
articles (collection)
-words (array of objects {"note", "word"} ) 
-translations (array of objects {"translation", "examples"} )
--examples (array of objects {"example", "translation"} ) that means 
 examples of word usage with it's translation.
```

The {{> quickForm collection=articles ... }} are working fine, but I want to change template and functionality by some conditions...

I tried to use

```
{{#autoForm collection=articles id="insertArticleForm" class="article-form" }}
        {{#afEachArrayItem name='words'}}
            {{> afFieldInput name=this.current.note placeholder='schemaLabel' class="note"}}
            {{> afFieldInput name=this.current.word placeholder='schemaLabel' class="word"}}
            <button type="button" class="autoform-remove-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
        {{/afEachArrayItem}}
        <button type="button" class="autoform-add-item" data-autoform-field="words"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

But it doesn't work. 
It looks like this old issue: [Meteor: Custom AutoForm with array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109823/meteor-custom-autoform-with-array-of-objects/26109824#26109824)
but it seems after some recent updates of [Meteor/Autoform](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform), this syntax doesn't work.... and author of plugin doesn't answer on issues for months (

When I changed {{> afFieldInput name=this.current.note }}  to {{> afFieldInput name='words.$.note' }} it seems like working , form appears with all need fields, but nothing are submit on the server. Even in this simple example, without nested fields...